# Парсинг JSON с записью в RecyclerView во Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Пытаюсь записать JSON значения в RecyclerView во фрагмент, изначально вывод был в activity_main (делал по туториалу). Не выводит данные(API проверил), ошибок нет. Данные получаю с url. Подскажите пожалуйста, как быть?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.hfad.fin.StockFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

fragment_stock.xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

row.xml(CardView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cardView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TICKER"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TICKER"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DATE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DATE"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TIME"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TIME"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CLOSE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLOSE"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    String TICKER = null;
    String DATE = null;
    String TIME = null;
    String CLOSE = null;

    class APITask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            String response=null;
            try {
                response = getResponseFromUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);     
                        TICKER = jsonObject.getString("TICKER");
                        DATE = jsonObject.getString("DATE");
                        TIME = jsonObject.getString("TIME");
                        CLOSE = jsonObject.getString("CLOSE");
                        DATE=DATE.replaceAll("/", ".");

                        StockFragment.TICKER.add(TICKER);
                        StockFragment.DATE.add(DATE);
                        StockFragment.TIME.add(TIME);
                        StockFragment.CLOSE.add(CLOSE);
                        } 
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                //
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        URL generateURL = generateURL();
        new APITask().execute(generateURL);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

StockFragment.java

```
public class StockFragment extends Fragment {
    static ArrayList<String> TICKER = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> DATE = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> TIME = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> CLOSE = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stock,container,false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        GetDataWithApiHelperAdapter adapter = new GetDataWithApiHelperAdapter(TICKER, DATE, TIME, CLOSE);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        return view;
    }
```

}

GetDataWithApiHelperAdapter.java

```
public class GetDataWithApiHelperAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GetDataWithApiHelperAdapter.MyViewClass> {
    ArrayList<String> TICKER;
    ArrayList<String> DATE;
    ArrayList<String> TIME;
    ArrayList<String> CLOSE;


    public GetDataWithApiHelperAdapter( ArrayList<String> TICKER, ArrayList<String> DATE, ArrayList<String> TIME, ArrayList<String> CLOSE){
        this.TICKER=TICKER;
        this.DATE=DATE;
        this.TIME=TIME;
        this.CLOSE=CLOSE;
}

    public MyViewClass onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        MyViewClass myViewClass=new MyViewClass(view);
        return myViewClass;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewClass holder, int position) {
        holder.TICKER.setText(TICKER.get(position));
        holder.DATE.setText(DATE.get(position));
        holder.TIME.setText(TIME.get(position));
        holder.CLOSE.setText(CLOSE.get(position));
    }

    public int getItemCount(){
        return TICKER.size();
    }

    public class MyViewClass extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView TICKER;
        TextView DATE;
        TextView TIME;
        TextView CLOSE;
        public MyViewClass(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            TICKER = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TICKER);
            DATE = itemView.findViewById(R.id.DATE);
            TIME = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TIME);
            CLOSE = itemView.findViewById(R.id.CLOSE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Собственно в ошибке вам подсказано и решение - добавить что-то такое в тэг fragment в разметке activity_main - `android:id="@+id/fragment"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , спасибо. Но появились другие ошибки, добавил выше

Comment: Приведённый в вопросе код не может такую ошибку выкинуть. У вас явно код уже поменялся. У вас NPE, в активити явно остался код перенесённый во фрагмент

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , еще раз посмотрел, где-то я накосячил, прошу прощение. Запустил еще раз, ничего не выводит, ошибок нет, но и вывода никакого нет, экран пустой. API проверил, результат по URL выводит

Comment: Скорее всего дело в том, что вы фрагмент (и адаптер в нём) инициализируете раньше чем приходят данные с сервера. В итоге изначально данных ноль, а когда они появятся - вы адаптеру об этом не сообщаете. Имея в виду, что предлагаемое мною - лютый костыль, коий ни в коем случае нельзя использовать в реальной жизни, вы можете так сделать: 1. RecyclerView во фрагменте сделать публичным и статическим. 2. После получения данных - создать адаптер для RecyclerView с пришедшими с сервера данными. 3. Присвоить адаптер RecyclerView. 4. Уведомить адаптер об изменении данных через notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Чтобы исправить этот код достаточно избавиться от фрагмента, тогда и статики не будут нужны и доступ к адаптеру будет. То есть перенести все в активити, и в onPostExecute вызывать adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). 
Кстати парсинг json'а также можно делать в фоне, т.е. в doInBackground.
А так, лучше, конечно, переписать, пока не поздно. А то появятся сервисы, ресиверы, хэндлеры и прочая из времен донатов с капкейками...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , спасибо

Comment: @Yura Ivanov , спасибо